# FOSUser - Remember me functionality issue

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, fosuserbundle

I have built a website with symfony 2.8, I use FOSUserBundle for authentication, user management etc, and I have an issue that I can solve.
For no apparent reason to me, the "rememberme" cookie won't act like as expected.

I pretty sure I've just missed a config parameter in some way but I'm looking for it since hours and can't find it.

I'm using php 7.0 on an apache 2.0 server.

There is my config.yml file (in most part) :

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
        save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions/"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

...

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User

    from_email:
        address:        "%email_referer%"
        sender_name:    "App"
    group:
        group_class:    UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager:  sonata.user.orm.group_manager
    resetting:
        email:
            template: :mail:resetting_password.html.twig
    service:
        mailer:         fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
        user_manager:   sonata.user.orm.user_manager
```

And there is my security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_CHAMPION:    [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_ENTREPRISE:  [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_A, ROLE_B]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        SONATA:
            - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin
            context: user
            form_login:
                provider:               fos_userbundle
                login_path:             login
                use_forward:            true
                check_path:             sonata_user_admin_security_check
                failure_path:           null
                default_target_path:    sonata_admin_dashboard
            logout:
                path:               sonata_user_admin_security_logout
                target:             homepage
                invalidate_session: false
            anonymous:  true

        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: .*
            context: user
            form_login:
                provider:               fos_userbundle
                login_path:             login
                use_forward:            false
                check_path:             /login_check
                failure_path:           null
                csrf_token_generator:   security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path:    profile
            logout:
                path:               logout
                target:             homepage
                invalidate_session: false
            anonymous: true
            remember_me:
                secret:     '%secret%'
                lifetime:   15724800 # 6 months
                path:       /
                domain:     ~
                secure:     true

    access_control:
        # Some public pages
        - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/cgu$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/cgv$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/contact$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/faq$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/connexion, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Admin login page needs to be accessed without credential
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        # - { path: ^/admin/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Admin
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
        # Partie connectée
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }

    acl:
        connection: default
```

**EDIT:**

I did some tests and it appears that my REMEMBERME cookie is not deleted, its still here, with the same startdate and enddate than before.

So, I can close and open my browser, the cookie is still here and when I do this I'm still authenticated (and can go to the admin). But when I just stay "idle" for a period of time and I want to access to the admin section, I'm redirected to the login page.
The REMEMBERME cookie still exists, but at this point, I can't access to the page I could when I was starting my browser.

**EDIT 2 :**
It appears the session lifetime is the "cause" of my problems. But what I want is that when a user check "Remember me" option he has no longer need to login again, even if he keep a tab of my site open for x days in background (like a mobile browser do). How can I do that ?

**EDIT 16/08/2017 :**
I've added a line in my security.yml file :
   domain: ~
It appears that this line make the system work. The issue is no longer detected on my computer with Chrome and Firefox (in case one of these two was playing with my cookies).

PS : I will update this ticket in some days, to "validate" it, if the problem don't show up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue no longer appears, the solution seems to be the "domain" parameter :

```
domain:     ~
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about your session lifetime more than remember me feature.

In your config.yml you can configure the framework to use a custom session lifetime.

```
framework:
     session:
         cookie_lifetime: 3600
```

If this configuration is not set, the value from your php.ini will be used.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What I understand here is if a tab is open for more than 3600 seconds the user will have to login again. What I want is when a user check "Remember me" option, he no longer has to login again. How can I make this possible ?